# Woocommerce hide out of stock variation price from variable price range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to hide out of stock variation price from woocommerce variable products price-range

for example i have product that has 2 variation, one of them sold out but in price range it's still showing old price for sold out variation

i want to show price range only for available (in stock) variations

[image]

I searched a lot and did't find any solution
Found this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price_ofs', 10, 2 );

function remove_price_ofs( $price, $product ) {
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && (is_product() || is_product_category() || is_shop() )) {$price = '';}
return $price;
}
```

but it's only hide price from product itself, but in price range it's still showing out of stock variation price

Thanks all in advance for help!

Comment: Use the option - "Hide out of stock items from the catalog" from your Woo Settings -> Products - Inventory

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don’t want to hide out of stock variation itself, i want to hide out of stock variation price from price range